# I couldn't deploy my web-service in Talend Runtime Container

Tags: deployment, talend

I've created Apache CXF project of SOAP service in IntelliJ Idea framework to deploy in Talend Runtime ESB container.
When I put my kar-file or jar-file in deploy-directory there is no error messagges in log-file
but there is no endpoint-address of my soap-service in cxf-list of talend runtime container at 8040 port and my service isn't accessible.
There is no my kar-file in osgi:list.
If I deploy jar-file of my project I can see it in osgi:list like Active, but endpoint-address isn't accessible.
Tell me please, what may be the reason of it?

I tried to put kar-file or jar-file of my project to deploy directory, but my soap-service isn't accessible.
Although I can see my jar-file in osgi:list as Active

This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>HospitalAdmissionDischarged</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <cxf.version>2.0.13</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>42.2.27.jre7</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.priv.bang.karaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql-jdbc-karaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <type>xml</type>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0.v20120529-1548</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>kar</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>hospital_admission_discharge_filter</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <version>2.3.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                        <instructions>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                            <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
<!--                            <Private-Package></Private-Package>-->
                                <Export-Package>ru.rintech.isomp.*</Export-Package>
                            <Bundle-Activator>ru.rintech.isomp.hospital_admission_discharge.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                            <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework;
                                javax.servlet-api;
                                cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws;
                            </Import-Package>
                            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```